# How scroll over a disabled TextField with fixed number of lines in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, scroll, textfield

> After i set 'enable: false' i can't see the others lines if a text has more than 9 lines. I need set 'enable:false' because i don't want user edit text in this TextField. I tried use SigleChildScrollView, but it didn't work...

```
            Container(
                    child:  SingleChildScrollView(
                      child: TextField(
                        enabled: false,
                        keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
                        maxLines: 9,
                        controller: chatController,
                        decoration: InputDecoration(

                        hintText: "Chat...",

                        border: OutlineInputBorder(

                       borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
```

Comment: Mark the text field as readOnly instead of disabled.

Comment: use `Text` widget if it is always disabled

Comment: I maked it as readOnly an it works! Thank you!

Answer (score 8):

**make readOnly: true**
now you can't edit the field and still you can scroll the field.

TextFormField(
enabled: true,
readOnly: true,
initialValue: 'initial value',
)